# Ubuntu 18.04 - no DNS query

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, routing

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. I am trying to ping other computers on my local network using their hostname but it's not working.

```
$ ping ubuntudesktop
ping: ubuntudesktop: Name or service not known
```

I have the name servers for the wifi adapter set up as follows:
[Wifi adapter DNS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfXoo.png)

I am snooping the wifi packets using wireshark and I do not see any DNS query when I run the ping command. Why are these nameservers not being used?

On a side note - when I use nslookup for google.com for example I get the following:

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.14.238
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:400a:803::200e
```

I am assuming Server is the address of the DNS server? Isn't 127.0.0.53 an address for the loopback interface? Would this mean it's essentially querying itself?

Comment: Where are you expecting this information to come *from*? DNS doesn't usually resolve unqualified local network names - mDNS / Bonjour / Avahi may do so for addresses of the form `ubuntudesktop.local`. Otherwise you will need to use the `files` mechanism (by adding a suitable entry into your local computer's `/etc/hosts` file)

Comment: from the local router

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.53 is the address used by [systemd-resolved.service](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html)

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1224/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           1224/systemd-resolv
```

Hostnames of other computers will not be resolved trough the DNS service.

You need to specify them in `/etc/hosts` statically.

Example:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 mypc

192.168.1.100 ubuntudesktop
```

You can edit this file trough sudo

```
sudo editor /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I have another computer on my network that does us DNS to resolve hostnames. If I understand it correctly the DNS service will query the router and it will resolve the hostname to the local IP address.

Comment: So you need to provide your DNS servers at DHCP level or specify them in the systemd-resolved service or though NetworkManager (System settings -> Network).

Comment: Do you have the libnss-resolve package installed? That may fix the /etc/nsswitch.conf to actually use dns in some cases.

Comment: I have the DNS servers configured in the settings for the wifi adapter (see the screenshot listed on the post). Are these settings being ignored?

Comment: On the computer that is working (16.04) the /etc/resolv.conf includes a search domain and the one that is not working (18.04) does not. How do I add a search domain in 18.04? It's not available in the network settings of the adapter.

Comment: @iamthebull does this help? [How to set domain search on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082634/178692)